# Raspberry Pi 4 I2C bus was working, but fails after reboot

Tags: raspberry-pi, i2c

I have an SSD1306 OLED display and RPi4. I used the tutorial from https://maker.pro/raspberry-pi/projects/raspberry-pi-monitoring-system-via-oled-display-module which (after a small mod) was working up until I updated /etc/rc.local and did a reboot.
Since then, I get nothing.

```
sudo i2cdetect -y 1 now gives me:

     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

I had created an image of the SD Card before setting up the OLED, and restoring the image and trying again I still can't detect the OLED.

I'd appreciate any tips or thoughts on resolving this.

Comment: I've connected the OLED to a D1 Mini I use for testing, and it's fine. The issue is def with the RPi.

Comment: What did you set in /boot/config.txt?

Comment: I had made no changes to /boot/config.txt, but for some reason it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is unknown. I left the Pi run for a while, then tried again and it just worked.